# JAAS via WildFly

Tags: java, authentication, wildfly, wildfly-8, jaas

I want to use a JAAS-Authentication in a JAVA application via WildFly (8.2.0).

I have tried several methods and configurations....but I still get errors at the login (LoginContext).

I have started to configure the standalone.xml (WildFly):

- created a new security realm „TPRealm“ with the JAAS-authentication:

  ```
  <security-realm name="TPRealm">
       <authentication>
           <jaas name="TPLogin"/>
       </authentication>
  </security-realm>
  ```
- set the realm as default?:

  ```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:2.0">
       <endpoint worker="default"/>
          <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="TPRealm"/>
  </subsystem>
  ```
- at Last, I have created a security domain „TPLogin“ with the login module:

  ```
  <security-domain name="TPLogin" cache-type="default">
      <authentication>
          <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
              <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/TourPlanningDS"/>
              <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select passwordHash from TaUser where login=?"/>
          </login-module>
      </authentication>
  <security-domain>
  ```

**In Java:**

```
String username = "Admin";
String password = "admin";

PasswordClientCallbackHandler handler = new PasswordClientCallbackHandler(username, "TPRealm", password.toCharArray());

try {
      LoginContext loginContext = new LoginContext("TPRealm", handler);
      loginContext.login();
} catch (LoginException e) {
      System.out.println("Login failed");
      return;
}
```

At "new LoginContext(...)", I get following error

```
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for TPRealm
```

Moreoften I read, that a config-file is needed (jaas.config):

```
TPRealm {
      org.jboss.security.auth.spi.TPLogin required;  // I dont know, what exactly have to stay here
}
```

I added this file to the System.Properties.

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", jaasConfig)  //jaasConfig = path to file
```

With this, I can compile "new LoginContext(...)" but compiling failes at the next line at loginContext.login():

```
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: org.jboss.security.auth.spi.TPLogin
```

I also watched the log of wildfly expecting anything to be logged while running the code, but nothing was logged.

In the Java Application I have added also these properties:

```
Properties ejbProps = new Properties();
ejbProps.put("endpoint.name", "client-endpoint");
ejbProps.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "false");
ejbProps.put("remote.connections", "default");
ejbProps.put("remote.connection.default.host", "localhost");
ejbProps.put("remote.connection.default.port", "8080");                                                  
ejbProps.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "false");

EJBClientConfiguration cc = new PropertiesBasedEJBClientConfiguration(ejbProps);
ContextSelector<EJBClientContext> selector = new ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector(cc);
EJBClientContext.setSelector(selector);
```

Do I need to set further properties?
Should I take notice on something else?

I would be really pleased, if anyone could help me.

Comment: What do you have in your web.xml?